# How to extract information from a json file in python

Tags: python, json

I have below json file:

```
{
   "Data":[
      {
        "Name": "User1",
        "Id": "7",
        "Level" : "1"
      },
      {
        "Name": "User2",
        "Id": "8",
        "Level" : "2"
      },
      {
        "Name": "User3",
        "Id": "9",
        "Level" : "3"
      }
  ],
}
```

Now from my code, I get the value of `Id` and based on that I need to extract its `Name` and `Level`. How can I do this.?

For example, for Id `7` I need to extract `User1` and `1` for name and level respectively

Comment: you may be interested in built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html) library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple loop. d is your JSON as python dict.

```
for l in d["Data"]:
    if l["Id"] == "7":
        print(l["Name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Open JSON file in a variable and then query. Like this-

```
import json
with open('your_json_file.json') as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
    for d in data["Data"]:
       if d["Id"] == your_id:
          print d
          break
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, You may even simply filter

```
 filter(lambda d: d['Id'] == '7', json_data['Data'])
```